# System.NullReferenceException while creating a Details View Site Model that has a field from Region model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

Details.cshtml (For Site)

This is the part of the code causing problem

```
<b>Region: </b>
<a asp-controller="Regions" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.RegionID">
@Model.Region.Name
</a>
</p>
```

my site model has a field called RegionID which represents the region in which the site is located and when i am trying to retrieve the Region name to display it in the details view of the site i am getting the System.NullReferenceException

Any Idea on how i can solve this issue would be appreciated[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix you ef code in Details action

```
var model= await context...
.Include(r=> r.Region)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a default value for `Model.Region`:

```
public class YourModel{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public Region Region { get; set; } = new Region();
}
public class Region {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```